# Reload javascript variables with setinterval function

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am trying to learn Google Gauges with Google visualization and i want to display the data on the Gauge which changes every second and am loading the variable using a PHP command which assigns the variable as seconds value using shell_exec function, PFB my code

```
setInterval(function() {
var memory = parseFloat(<?php echo json_encode(shell_exec("date +%S")); ?>);
data.setValue(0, 1, memory);
chart.draw(data, options);
    }, 1000);
```

after the function is being called after 1 second the value of `memory` is not being refreshed and taken from `parseFloat(<?php echo json_encode(shell_exec("date +%S")); ?>);`

Please let me know how do i make the `memory` variable reload everytime the function is called after 1 second

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done that using two separate files, a PHP file to get the data from a database (in my case) and a javascript file that gets the response from the database using the PHP file and Ajax.

You have to include Ajax adding this to your index.html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript code:

```
var mysqlData; // Global variable in witch the data will be stored
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/getdata.php", // file name or path to PHP file
        dataType: "JSON",
        data:{},
        success: function(x){
            mysqlData = x;  // Assign the response to global variable mysqlData
        }
    });
}, 2000); // Run every 2 seconds
```

Then in the google Gauge function do something like this:

```
function SOC() {
    // Normal google chart code goes here 
    setInterval(function() {
        data.setValue(0, 1, mysqlData["SOC"] ); // In my case mysqlData is an object which contains the key "SOC"
        formatter.format(data, 1); // Only needs to be done if google.visualization.NumberFormat have been used
        chart.draw(data, options); // To redraw the gauge with new data
    }, 2000);
}
```

In the PHP file:

```
<?php
/* Get your data */
echo json_encode($table);
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this approach helped :-)

Answer (score 2):

The current issue is that your php code is only executed once, the values are therefore not updated: `<?php echo json_encode(shell_exec("date +%S")); ?>` returns a single value, which is not updated periodically from your front end.

I would suggest you to use Javascript's `Date` instead:

```
var seconds = new Date() / 1000;
```

Comment: Antony, thanks for the reply, but my requirement is to load a variable from a php code in future, i had used the date command in PHP just as a test data, is there a way i can refresh this data without reloading my complete page?

Comment: You could use Ajax and build a `getUpdatedValue.php` php page which would only return the new value